# Regular expression method for swap case

Tags: regex

I am new in python. I would like to write a python script that will swap case. In other words, convert all lowercase letters to uppercase letters and vice versa. I managed to performed tasks with using following scripts.

```
def swap_case(text):
    newstring=""
    for letter in text:
        if (letter.isupper())==True:
            newstring+=(letter.lower())
        elif (letter.islower())==True:
                newstring+=(letter.upper())
        elif (letter.isspace())==True:
                newstring+=letter
        else:
            newstring+=letter
    return newstring
text="StaCkOverfLow.cOm"
print(swap_case(text))
```

output: sTAcKoVERFlOW.CoM

However, I have strongly believed that code can be shortened by using the regular expression. 
Would you please optimize the code and give some hints?

Comment: If the code works, you should post to [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: There is a [str.swapcase()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase) function that can do this for you.

Comment: Thanks, JJJ for directing me to right direction. I was not aware of the code review feature in the StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, Eugenhu for your str.swapcase() function hint. it worked very well in my case.